# Unity A* pathfinding - Get current velocity or direction of instance moving along path

Tags: unity-game-engine, a-star

Im working on RTS 2D izometric game and i wanna use A* pathfinding for moving units. I need to know current direction of instance, which is moving along the path.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you've tried out.

Comment: I have prefab called Soldier which has Seeker and AI Destination components. It also has animator, which control animations for walking left,right,up,down and attacking in these 4 directions. When this soldier is moving along the A* path, it should display animation that he is moving in some direction. I can´t find function which will return current direction of soldir moving along the path.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution, in my opinion, is to look at the `AIPath` object's `desiredVelocity` field, which points in the direction that your unit wants to go. For example:

```
    private void Update() {
      // Point the creature in the direction of movement
      if (_aiDestination.target != null) {
        _spriteRenderer.flipX = (_aiPath.desiredVelocity.x > 0.0f);
      }
    }
```

Docs [here](https://arongranberg.com/astar/documentation/dev_4_1_0_9f8b6eb7/class_pathfinding_1_1_a_i_base.php#a52a5f75a7b8a9e7a03152c01f92d36c6).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I used variable to store previous position and then compare it to current position. From that i could determine in which direction is instance moving.